# TypeError: Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type float

Tags: python, floating-point, typeerror

import pyglet
class CarMap:

```
def __init__(self):


    self.in_map = [341, 161, 452, 121, 567, 123, 650, 160, 678, 241, 613, 340, 654, 467, 611, 508, 506, 514, 416, 437,
               289, 401, 207, 431, 130, 469, 110, 424, 128, 320, 157, 229, 95, 99, 217, 87]
    self.out_map = [344, 89, 445, 45, 572, 59, 691, 92, 756, 229, 695, 333, 715, 482, 649, 566, 455, 567, 409, 502, 319,
                476, 214, 492, 125, 550, 78, 557, 45, 485, 41, 353, 87, 254, 38, 88, 74, 35, 271, 44, 295, 70]
    self.score_lines = [341, 161,344, 89,567, 123,572, 59,678, 241,756, 229,654, 467,715, 482,506, 514,455, 567,130, 469,125, 550,157, 229,87, 254,95, 99,74, 35]
#self.score_lines = [654, 467,715, 482,506, 514,455, 567,416,437,409,502,289,401,319,476,207,431,214,492,130, 469,125, 550,157, 229,87, 254,95, 99,74, 35]
    self.in_batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
    self.out_batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
    self.in_grey = [160] * (len(self.in_map) / 2.0)
    self.out_grey =[160] * (len(self.out_map) / 2.0)
    self.blue1 = [0, 39, 102,1]*(len(self.score_lines)/2.0)
    self.blue2 = [0, 97, 255, 1] * (2)
    self.in_batch.add(len(self.in_map) / 2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINE_LOOP, None, ('v2i', self.in_map),
                  ('c4B', self.in_grey * 4))
    self.out_batch.add(len(self.out_map) / 2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINE_LOOP, None, ('v2i', self.out_map),
                   ('c4B', self.out_grey * 4))

def draw(self,score_activate):

    self.in_batch.draw()
    self.out_batch.draw()
    score_batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
    score_batch.add(16,pyglet.gl.GL_LINES,None,('v2i',self.score_lines),('c4B',self.blue1))
    score_batch.draw()
    score_batch2 = pyglet.graphics.Batch()
    score_batch2.add(2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINES, None, ('v2i', self.score_points(score_activate)), ('c4B', self.blue2))
    score_batch2.draw()

def score_points(self,score_activate):

    if score_activate == 7:


        score_activate = -1
    return self.score_lines[score_activate*4+4:score_activate*4+8]
```

I got a Error in Line :
 self.blue1 = [0, 39, 102,1]*(len(self.score_lines)/2.0)
which is can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'...can anyone plz solve this?..I am using Python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

When you multiply a list by `x` in python, it doesn't multiply each item of the list, it only repeats the sequence `x` times. That's why `x` must be an integer and can't be a floating point. Try this line instead if you want to get the elements of the list multiplied :

```
self.blue1 = [k*(len(self.score_lines)/2.0) for k in [0, 39, 102,1]]
```

Similarly change the code where possibly a list of integers is getting multiplied by a float. Try the following if you want to repeat the list `x` times :

```
self.blue1 = [0, 39, 102,1]*int(len(self.score_lines)/2.0) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [1,2] * 2
[1, 2, 1, 2]
>>>'abc' * 3
'abcabcabc'
```

When you multiply a list with an integer, it causes the elements of the list to be repeated that many times. The same behaviour is observed when multiplying integers with strings.
You can see why multiplying with a float is not supported for this operation.

If you want to multiply each element of the list by a float, you can do this:

```
>>>ls = [num * 5.5 for num in [1,2,3]]
>>>ls
[5.5, 11.0, 16.5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant multiply a list like that. If you would do that with an integer the list will be appended N times with itself: [1,2,3]*3 = [1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3].

You can do this with a for loop within a list which defines the new list:

```
self.blue1 = [0, 39, 102,1]
self.blue1 = [i*len(self.score_lines)/2.0) for i in self.blue1]
```

or in one go:

```
self.blue1 = [i*len(self.score_lines)/2.0) for i in [0, 39, 102,1]]
```

You could also resort to numpy, which does allow multiplication like in your code.

add import to the top of your code:
    import numpy as np

Then the following yields the same result, only now self.blue1 is a numpy array:

```
self.blue1 = np.array([0, 39, 102,1])*len(self.score_lines)/2.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

self.blue1 = [0, 39, 102,1]*int(len(self.score_lines)/2.0)

Here I used len to convert it into integer form,simple!

Comment: This doesnt provide a correct answer for the question, has the same issue described by other people who have answered